# How do I align the the email input box and and subscription button on mobile view properly?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to align the email input box and subscription button of this website on mobile displays via the 450px media query. However, the button and subscription box appears to be aligned properly when viewed in chrome's mobile emulator but they are not aligned properly when viewed on an actual mobile device e.g. iPhone 5 Safari.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by not aligned properly ? maybe telling how do you want it to be aligned & how is it behaving now would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your alignment problems are caused by padding introduced in this media query on the email field in `front.css` at row 106:

```
@media (max-width: 450px) {
#mce-EMAIL{
    padding-right: 13px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Try removing all paddings and leave the margin bottom (needed on a tiny wiewport when the button jumps below the input field).

[also apparently a closing curly bracket is missing at the end of this media query]

Answer (score 0):

Setting your viewport properly should solve the problem.

Add the following code to the head section of your HTML template:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

This tells the browser to set the page width as the default width

And don't forget when filling property values for sizes always use Relative sizes(i.e 100%)